# uploading folder in github using git bash

Tags: git, github, push

I have watched tonnes of videos and looked into many solutions to upload my local repository to my github repository using gitbash, everything goes well but when I try to push my folder to the origin master it says invalid ref, and is this a git repository? I don't know what the problem is, I am trying to solve this for the past 3 days.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y8WF.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The remote url contains hello-world twice.

You can update it using set-remouteurl aa described here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories